# Efficient data-structure for 2D minimum value with updates?

Tags: data-structures

I want a data-structure to fetch the minimum value in a subgrid of a 2D grid, where the cells in the 2D grid would update once in a while. What is the optimal approach to use in this case?

For example I would want the smallest value from [0, 0] to [2, 2] in a grid of size 4x4. Thanks!

Comment: This is a classic application of a two-dimensional segment tree. See here: http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Segment_tree#Extension_to_two_or_more_dimensions

Comment: What do you mean by 'minimum'? Minimum x, minimum y, or some (euclidean) distance to [0,0]?

Comment: Minimum value. So if the subarray is [[3, 1], [4, 21]], I would return 1.